# How to unsubcribe the event in a main view model that subscribe event of secondary view model?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a main view model that uses a secondary view model. The main view model subscribe to an event of the secondary view model.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    SecondViewModel _secondViewModel;

    public MainViewModel (SecondViewModel paramSecondViewModel)
    {
        _secondViewModel = paramSecondViewModel;
        _secondViewModel.MyEvent += MyeventHandler;
    }

    private void MyEventHandler(object sender, eventargs e)
    {
        //Do something.
    }
}
```

In the main view model, I inject an instance of the second view model and then I subscribe to its event.

I think that when the main view model is not more needed, it can't be deleted because there is a cycle of references between the main view model and the second view model.

Suppose the main view model is tried to be deleted. It can't be deleted because the second view model has a reference because of the event.

If the second view model is tried to be deleted, it can't be deleted because the main view model can't be deleted.

Is this true or I am wrong that there is a cycle of references?

The cycle life of both view models are similar, when I delete de main view model, the second view model is not needed, so at first it seems that memory leak will not happen, but I am not sure if this is true or not.

So my question is, how the cycle life of both view models are similar, it is needed to do something or GC will collect them? If GC collection can't collect them because of the cycle, how could I ensure that will they be collected? Should I implement IDisposable in both view models? Only in the main view model? Or implement IDisposable is not the best solution?

I was trying the weak reference messenger of community toolkit, but I have realize if I use the second view model in different places, how the subscription is in the manager, that is global to the app, some view models receives the notification and I don't know to filter it, so I wanted to implement the events with delegates in the "old way".

So in summary: I would have memory leak if I don't do anything? If yes, how could I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR: The cyclic reference graph between the `MainViewModel` and the `SecondViewModel` instances is not preventing garbage collection of both as long as nothing else in your program is holding onto a reference of either of these two instances. The code as presented in the question does not constitute a memory leak, assuming MyEvent is an instance event and not a static event.*

Basically, the garbage collector doesn't care about cyclic object graphs. Rather, the garbage collector tracks/marks objects that still can be reached from what is called a root. Roots in an application are for example static fields, local variables on a thread's stack, CPU registers, GC handles, and the finalize queue, to name a few. Any object that's not reachable (anymore) from any of the application roots will be subject to garbage collection.

Note that in your example, the cyclic reference graph is realized by an instance field and what appears to be an instance event. None of which are roots themselves.<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore, if both the `MainViewModel` instance and the `SecondViewModel` instance cannot be reached from any of the applications roots<sup>[2]</sup>, then both will be garbage collected even when they hold references of each other.

With respect to the code in your question (and *only* with respect to the code in your question), and under the assumption `SecondViewModel.MyEvent` is indeed an instance event as it appears to be: No, this code alone won't create a memory leak.

Further reading, if you want to dig into .NET garbage collection:

- [Fundamentals of garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)
- [dotnet/runtime's Garbage Collection Design document](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/coreclr/botr/garbage-collection.md)
  (including links to further publications)
- [.NET GC Internals Youtube video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpUkQYy-K8Y-wYcDgDXKhfs6OT8fFQtVm)
- Bonus tidbit:
  [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2000/november/garbage-collection-automatic-memory-management-in-the-microsoft-net-framework)
  (Historical document from the year 2000 or so about garbage collection in the very first .NET framework version. While implementation details of the garbage collector and the related data structures might differ between .NET Framework, .NET Core, current and future .NET versions, the broader concept of how garbage collection works in .NET should still be the same, more or less.)

---

<sup>[1]</sup> It would be an entirely different story if for example `_secondViewModel` were a *static* field. With static fields being roots, the `SecondViewModel` instance would be rooted and thus neither it nor the `MainViewModel` instances referenced by its `MyEvent` event multi-cast delegate would be eligible for garbage collection.

<sup>[2]</sup> In other words: no root and nothing else being rooted holds a reference to either the `MainViewModel` or `SecondViewModel` instance.